How can I cap or extend a drain pipe cut flush with a retaining wall?
I have a retaining wall in which there is a drainage pipe. How can I extend this drainage pipe so I can put a cap it extend it?
Right I am not able to as the pipe is short and flush with the retaining wall. Any ideas?


Why would you cap the drain pipe? It is there for a good reason (assuming you like the wall).

Because I was a build raise garden bed after 2 feet of wall. It’s get muddy in heaving raining

Well, how do you feel about the retaining wall collapsing because of all the water behind it? Route that drain away from the area appropriately and design a raised bed that incorporates that solution.

@JonCuster, I am not building retaining wall on my wall, it’s just 2 feet far from wall.
This is my retaining wall. https://youtu.be/zcSehuqIpTU?si=KR0crevsHy-hR4Yw

I'm not clear on the intent here—how do you cap and extend a pipe?

Drain pipe like this isn't really intended to be completely watertight. It mostly provides a low-resistance path for drainage. As such, it's not critical that you get a perfect seal with your connections. So just use a common splicer intended for the purpose:

source
You'll need to secure the attached pipe so the fittings don't pull apart. Since you're building a garden bed you can probably drive some stakes and wire or clamp to those.

One could even use some stainless screws to more securely fasten the bits together—looks like there might be enough length exposed on the existing pipe.
